# ERC-20 Airdrop Smart Contract Vs ETH Airdrop Smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum

Hi am using a smart contract to airdrop erc-20 tokens:

```
contract ERC20 {
  function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract Airdrop {
  function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Though i am unable to airdrop ETH using it, can anyone tell me what i am missing or what loops must be added to the existing code to let it able to airdrop eth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
contract AirdropEth {
  function drop(address[] recipients, uint256[] values) payable public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      recipients[i].transfer(values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But I didn't test it, you should add more checks for production.